# Sequelize how to use one column in multiples uniques pairs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize 3.30.4.

I know how to make unique column using

```
label: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
}
```

I know how to make unique set using

```
catalogId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: 'label',
},
label: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: 'label',
}
```

I am looking for a solution where catalogId is part of both label and reference unique pair.
I can't use a single uniqu constraint it would allow duplicate label by changing reference and vice versa

```
catalogId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: [ 'label', 'reference' ],
},
label: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: 'label',
}
reference: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: 'reference',
}
```

Thanks you for any help or advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate migration for adding unique constraints.

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.addConstraint('tableName', ['column1', 'column2'], {
      type: 'unique',
      name: 'constraintmame',
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.removeConstraint('tableName', 'constraintName');
  },
};
```

This way, you can use `column1` and `column2` or any such column in multiple constraints.

Comment: How could I integrate it in my definition model I can't find out how to use queryInterface from sequelize instance
After using squelize.define("modelName", { ... }) can I call some sequelize.queryInterface.addConstraint ... ?